# How to save loaded data from Firebase Cloud Firestore to Arraylist

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new on Google Firebase and I'm trying to learn something about it. I am using Firestore to keeping data. I want to load data and save it in Arraylist.

[image]

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("test@gmail.com.total")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot querySnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    AList.add(new ReadModel(querySnapshot.getLong("lbs60"),
                            querySnapshot.getLong("lbs49"),
                            querySnapshot.getLong("lbs40"),
                            querySnapshot.getLong("lbs27"),
                            querySnapshot.getLong("lbs12")));
                    Log.d(TAG, querySnapshot.getId() + " => " + querySnapshot.getData());
                    if(AList.isEmpty()){
                        Log.d(TAG, AList.get(0).toString());
                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "ALIST is empty");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Why my Arraylist is empty?

Can I just load the lbs data?

Comment: hI This is because you put the condition wrong, it shoud be if(!AList.isEmpty())  not if(AList.isEmpty())

Comment: Have you solved the issue?